# How to display custom field using Views module at front end

Tags: views, 7, entities, nodes

I have created custom content type having below fields

```
Title, Description, Small Image, Large Image and Category
```

I am using **Views** module to display that content  (only small image) in **Grid** format with 4 columns. Issue is that i don't find any option (Settings of my view) to display only custom field  at front end. The only thing i can see is title is being displayed in grid format.

Does that mean **Views** module does not show custom fields created for a custom type content at front end?

****SOLVED****

Never mind guys. I got solution. Once you go to your view (created using views module) edit page then at the bottom of the page there is a section called Content having options to add custom fields in view.

Answer (score 1):

Views has the option of adding a custom field.
You need to search for global custom text field in the views
You can add a **global custom text field** as custom text field and alter the value using `hook_views_pre_render(&$view)`

```
function YOUR_THEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME':
      //  override the global custom text field value
      $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'My custom text';
    break;
  }
}
```

Click on the add as shown in the Image[image]

Then search for Global custom text field as shown in the Image[image]

You will see global custom text field which is custom text for views and you can alter it using above code or u can alter by entering html text into configure option for the field as shown in the image below :[image]

Comment: I am simply looking for a solution to be managed through admin interface not from code.

Comment: you can do the changes using admin interface

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended but still as an option, you can use [views_php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module it allows to add custom php fields in views, and if you just need custom text as custom field then @user13198 has already described it well enough.